# Get max attribute value in three input from XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Below is the sample xml file code. I want to get Max("Match") value using LINQ.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Match>
  <DOBMatch>100</ DOBMatch >
  <DOBScore>0</ DOBScore >
  <IDScore>89</ IDScore >
</Match>
```

Inside the Match object i have three value compare these three attribute (`DOBMatch,DOBScore,IDScore`)and get max value.

Below code get one value.

```
var info = document.Descendants("Match");
var finalInfo = info.Select(x => x.Element("DOBMatch ").Value).Max();
```

Comment: This? `var finalInfo = info.Select(x => Math.Max(x.Element("DOBMatch ").Value, x.Element("DOBScore").Value, x.Element("IDScore").Value)).Max();`

Comment: @Klamsi Math.Max - getting error as chnage 'MAx'  to ''Max magnitude.

Comment: Ah, you are right, then you will need a `new myType[] { ... }.Max()` instead of `Math.Max`

Comment: My type [] can you add full code

Comment: `var finalInfo = info.Select(x => new[] { x.Element("DOBMatch ").Value, x.Element("DOBScore").Value, x.Element("IDScore").Value }.Max()).Max();`

Comment: I don't believe your example can work as `Value` is a `string` and `Max()` won't be what you expect. You need to convert to `Int32`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to convert the values to `int` so you can find the maximum properly. Secondly, you need to get the three values desired:

```
var targetNames = new[] { "DOBMatch", "DOBScore", "IDScore" }.ToHashSet();
var info = document.Descendants("Match");
var finalInfo = info.SelectMany(d => d.Elements()
                                      .Where(d => targetNames.Contains(d.Name.ToString()))
                                      .Select(d => Int32.Parse(d.Value)))
                    .Max();
```

Answer (score -2):

var finalInfo = info.Elements().Max(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Value));